# Android: Pre-loading web page, then showing full screen

Tags: android, html, webview

For my Android app, I want to load a full web page in the background, then when it is ready show it in a full-screen view.  In other words, I want to show a fully-loaded web page without having the user sit through a "loading" screen.  Furthermore, I want to wait an arbitrary time, and not just show the page as soon as it's loaded.

It seems like the only way to show a full-screen web view is with a new Activity, but how do I pass the contents of the web page to the new Activity?  I tried calling *WebView.savePicture()* on a hidden webview then passing the results to a new Activity, but it seems like it won't save a picture unless it's actually visible.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a webview, either make it invisible or make it one view of ViewFlipper, and load the desired URL in it. Implement WebViewClient's onPageFinished for your webview. After receiving the callback (onPageFinished) wait for some arbitrary time (if you wish) and make your webview visible or flip to it and reload the URL. Reloading is important as page might have some javascript for redering certain section of webpage and if webview is not visible then it won't get executed. First load will make sure that all the required resources are cached, so second load will be instant.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems like the only way to show a full-screen web view is with a new Activity, but how do I pass the contents of the web page to the new Activity?

Do it in one activity:

Step #1: Make your `WebView` have `android:visibility="gone"` and have something else (whatever you want to show the user during your "arbitrary time") be visible.

Step #2: Have the `WebView` "load a full web page" while not visible.

Step #3: When the page is loaded, or when your "arbitrary time" has passed, make whatever you were showing have visibility of `GONE` and have the `WebView` return to being `VISIBLE`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  That's a great approach in general but I'm running into a couple of problems.  1) The Activity that I'm in is actually a Tab view, so I wouldn't be able to show the page full screen.  It would just fill the tab view.  2) This wouldn't let me hide the title bar if it's there.  Now I'm thinking to grab the HTML, parse it and download all of the referenced assets locally, then fire up a new Activity with the HTML edited to refer to the local assets.  It's much easier to show a full-screen popover view in iOS :(

Comment: @Bryan: If you are going to write shoddy questions (e.g., no mention of tabs or how they fit into the rest of your issue, no mention of the title bar or hot it fits into the rest of your issue), we cannot help you very well. "Now I'm thinking to grab the HTML, parse it and download all of the referenced assets locally, then fire up a new Activity with the HTML edited to refer to the local assets." -- that is ludicrous. "It's much easier to show a full-screen popover view in iOS :(" -- probably not, but perhaps you know how to write accurate and complete questions in iOS forums.

Comment: Yes, I apologize for not providing enough details originally.  Thank you again for the response above, it answered the question as it was written.

Comment: I wanna ask CommonsWare what is the better idea to load webpage in android as user should not wait for even a second. I have seen like how facebook does that... but in my case it took long time unless it fully loaded and then only I was able to see which is taking more than 40 seconds no matter what's the speed of internet